# OSXの2つのアプリケーションのフルスクリーンリサイズについて

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

いつもお世話になっています。今回は、ウィンドウの緑のボタンを長押しして画面半分ずつのフルスクリーンビューを2つのアプリで開いた時の挙動です。
Xcode等、純正のアプリはアプリケーションウィンドウの境目にマウスカーソルを置くと矢印が出て、ウィンドウの拡大・縮小（２つのウインドウのレイアウト比が変わる）出来るのですが、Google Chrome等を半分以上を占めるウィンドウサイズに変更しようとしても、縮小側の→しか出て来ず、Xcode等と挙動が異なります。自作のアプリではどこを設定すると、Xcodeやメモ帳の様に半分以上にも半分以下にもなる、分割フルスクリーンを実現できるのでしょうか。

Comment: 自分の環境だとChrome/Firefox、Chrome/Chromeの組み合わせで自由にサイズ変更できたのですが、Chromeとどのアプリで試したのでしょうか。なんか相方のアプリの最少ウインドウサイズが問題のような。Chromeウインドウ同士でも起こるならエクステンションを全て切っても同じですか？

Comment: ChromeとXcodeで上記現象が発生するので、内部で特別なことをしないといけないのかな？と思いました。ChromeとFirefoxだと確かに自由にリサイズできますね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split View（フルスクリーンを半分にする機能の名前）は特に専用のAPIがあるわけではなく、アプリがフルスクリーンに対応していれば使えます。ただ最少幅が設定されているとそれが尊重されます。
XCodeは最少幅が設定されているので、その値以下の細さにはできません。また同じ理由で最少幅が画面の半分以上のウインドウ同士（Mac Book Air上でのXCodeなど）をSplit Viewすることはでき無いようになっています。まともなアプリは大概最少ウインドウサイズが設定されています。これはUIがそれ以下では正しく表示できないかユーザーの使い勝手が著しく悪くなるからじゃないでしょうか。
ちなみにXCodeの場合ツールバーを消すともう少し細くできるので試してみてください（メニューバ=>表示）。

Comment: なるほど。原因がわかって安心しました。ありがとうございます。